# Adding buttons into collection SWT

Tags: java, button, swt

I have a problem with buttons. I found that when i add buttons into ArrayList, I will can manange every added button. But i don't have idea how to use setEnabled after adding it into ArrayList

```
public ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList();
buttons.add(newButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of them to setEnabled(true) then iterate through the array list as @DannyDaglas stated.

```
for(Button button : buttonList)
    button.setEnabled(true);
```

If you want to pick one of them in specific then you can enter the index of the button and setEnabled(true).

```
int index = 0;
buttonList.get(index).setEnabled(true);
```

If you are not sure about which index it is and you have objects of the buttons then you can do something like this

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<buttonList.size();i++){
    if(buttonList.get(i).equals(closeButton))
    buttonList.get(i).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array list with:

```
for(Button button : buttons)
    button.setEnabled(true);
```